# DNS settings to host site externally

Tags: dns

I have a domain that was purchased via Google Apps, the DNS management is through enom, but I wish to host the site elsewhere (but keep all of the Google apps services like docs, email, calendar as shown below). What do I need to change so I can point the site to my external hosting?

[image: DNS settings]

Answer (score 0):

updated the www record with new host